# Mutate redux persist state on development

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist to save my redux stage on AsyncStorage in react native. Since its a new app, I keep changing the structure of my redux initial state in order to accommodate new features or fixes. But when I reload the app, it gets overriden by the old state that was persisted by redux-persist (rehydration).

How do I get redux-persist to save the new initialState without having to write migrations on my development environment?

Answer (score 0):

I added a component function that clears the persisted state and reloads the app immediately. The function is called by button that is only available on the development environment.

```
import { persistor } from '../../AppContainer' // adjust this line for you
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'

clearPersistedState = () => {
    persistor.purge()
    RNRestart.Restart() // reload the React Native Bundle
}
```

Its necessary to reload the app immediately because if any redux action gets called after clearing the persisted state, redux-persist will again save the old initialState (that is still in RAM).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to accommodate new features and not deleting stuff that your views require then have automergelevel set to 2 as it will only override existing keys and anything new you add will be just added with the initialState you provide.